# Calculate variance between 2 columns in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

using ssrs, i have 2 fields in 2 columns which contain expressions. They calculate a percentage as follows:

```
FormatPercent(Fields!x.Value/Sum(Fields!x.Value))
```

and

```
FormatPercent(Fields!y.Value/Sum(Fields!y.Value))
```

I want a 3rd column which calulates the difference between these fields. How can I do this?

I cant use a calculated field to calculate the % for x and y as it uses an aggregate, hence I'm using expressions.

I don't want to add a 3rd expression which redoes the calculation for x and y as follows:

```
    FormatPercent(Fields!x.Value/Sum(Fields!x.Value)) - 
           FormatPercent(Fields!y.Value/Sum(Fields!y.Value))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- Name the text boxes that present the 2 different values (`txtXPercent` and `txtYpercent` say)
- Use the [`ReportItems`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx) collection to refer to these in the 3rd text box

Such as

```
=CInt(ReportItems!txtXPercent) - CInt(ReportItems!txtYpercent)
```

Comment: still can't get it to work, i think it might be because x and y have a FormatPercent in their expressions, so when trying to cast the textbox value to decimal or double it fails :|

Comment: ah, it needs a .Value as in CInt(ReportItems!txtXPercent.Value). Now I get #Error on my report